# How to create a hash from string for a unique-index database column?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to create a hash from a string-concatenated value. The resulting hash should lateron be used as a `unique index` in a `mysql` database.

Question: which type of hash would be most suitable for using it as a unique index in a database? The hash must always be the same for the same input, of course.

There are probably several choices:

```
string.hashCode();
UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(string.getBytes());
org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(string);
```

Background:

I want to import a 100GB+ csv file into a `mysql` database table. I'm in control of the csv file generation. The file is inserted via `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE INTO TABLE`...

I want to specify 20 out of 22 columns that should represent a `unique index`. If a row is loaded into the table and the unique index already exists, the row should just be skipped.

Therefore I'd probably have to use the `IGNORE` keyword in `LOAD DATA`.

BUT probably creating a unique index on 20 columns will slow the inserts down. As I only need the index for ignoring "duplicate" rows, I thought I could as well create some kind of additional `hash` column that I directly write into the csv file.

Question:

1) Is a single hash-column better for a unique-id, or should I create the unique id over 20 database columns?

2) How could I best create the unique `hash` on a large String that is concatenated of those 20 columns?

Sidenote: of course I need a safe hash, but also speed is important as I might also have to import several hundred GBs in shortest time possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SHA256 or MD5 for this. String.hashCode() will change every time you instantiate it.

Comment: `string.hashCode()` is not suppose to change for different instances, but it is still not usable for this purpose. It is only 32 bits and designed for speed, not collision resistance.

Comment: Though speed matters, so I have to find a reliable hash that still offers a good performance for millions of invocations...

Comment: @membersound by speed I mean `hashCode` is REALLY fast. It's purpose is memory hash table lookups :). SHA256 should be fine for your case. You can make a trigger to calculate it in MySQL to ensure its always updated.

Comment: @Vatev so you'd rater let the database calculate the hash, instead of precalculating it for the csv import?

Comment: Letting the DB calc the hashes will make things simpler (you can insert/update without worrying about the hash). I don't know if it will have a measurable effect on performance (you will need to test it).